# compare the date below current month c#

Tags: c#, linq

How to check the given date is less then or equal to the current month.
i.e., any datetime less then or equal to current month should return true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options;

1: find month start and compare:

```
var monthStart = new DateTime(when.Year, when.Month, 1);
if(someDate < monthStart) {...}
```

2: compare the month and year

```
if(someDate.Year < when.Year || (someDate.Year == when.Year &&
                         someDate.Month < when.Month)) {...}
```

either would be suitable for an extension method on `DateTime`

Comment: oh..i missed a part in the question, it is less than are equal to current month

Answer (score 6):

As an extension method:

```
public static bool IsBeforeStartOfCurrentMonth(this DateTime date) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime startOfCurrentMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
    return date < startOfCurrentMonth;
}
```

Usage:

```
DateTime date = // some DateTime
if(date.IsBeforeStartOfCurrentMonth()) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: +1 Wierd - I had almost the *exact* same answer, down to the variable names and everything.

Comment: @Andrew, maybe reading a lot of code on SO, a common naming system converges :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply compare the Year and Month values if the two DateTime values -

```
DateTime d1, d2;
...
d1.Year <= d2.Year && d1.Month < d2.Month;
```